# Html 5 content placeholder

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui, fabricjs

I have a requirement like what we can see in the below link,

http://custom.case-mate.com/diy?bypassLandingPage=true#design/iphone5_barelythere

after opening the link please select a layout from the left side of the editor, then a placeholder section will come over the canvas!, how i can achieve the same? are they using html or image? is there any specific libraries available which can help me achieve this ?
I know they are using jquery UI droppable for dragging and placing the image over the place holders, but how that layout area over the canvas works ?

I am using fabric.js in my project!
Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this!. also i must be able to export the canvas content as svg or png using the fabric js methods. doing anything should not affect on this.

Answer (score -1):

looking the editor with firebug you can see there are 4 total  elements, with one of them being a ui-droppable item.
there are many libraries aorund that extend default  behaviour, raphaelJS kinetikJs, threeJs; with a rapid google search [this](http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/top-7-javascript-canvas-libraries-and-tutorials/) link came out